# Dash-Plotly: keep dropdown selection on page reload

Tags: flask, dropdown, plotly-dash

Im quite new to web development in python and am developing a dash-plotly application at the moment. In the application there is a dropdown menu for the user to select a specific time interval for shown data in the graph. When the page is refreshed the selection returns obviously back to default. This simplified code shows the dropdown setup:

```
import dash_core_components as dcc

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    dcc.Store('memory-intervals', storage_type='session')
    dcc.Dropdown(
       id='time',
       options=get_intervals(),
       value=Interval.DAY.value,
       multi=False,
    ),
)
```

What I understood for now is, that I can store data in the browser session through dash's Store component. I managed to store selection like this:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('memory-intervals', 'data'),
    Input('time', 'value'),
)
def select_interval(interval):
    if interval is None:
        raise PreventUpdate

    return interval
```

So I am stuck at this point... how can set the store's data as selection value after page reload?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Dash **[persistence](https://dash.plotly.com/persistence)** feature.

As per documentation:

> persistence_type ('local', 'session', or 'memory'; default 'local'):
> Where persisted user changes will be stored:
>
> **memory:** only kept in memory, reset on page refresh. This is useful for
> example if you have a tabbed app, that deletes the component when a
> different tab is active, and you want changes persisted as you switch
> tabs but not after reloading the app.
>
> **local:** uses window.localStorage. This is the default, and keeps the
> data indefinitely within that browser on that computer.
>
> **session:** uses window.sessionStorage. Like 'local' the data is kept
> when you reload the page, but cleared when you close the browser or
> open the app in a new browser tab.

In your example, if you need to preserve a dropdown value only after reloading, but not after exiting the browser or closing the tab, you could write:

```
import dash_core_components as dcc

    app = dash.Dash(__name__)
    app.layout = html.Div(
        dcc.Store('memory-intervals', storage_type='session')
        dcc.Dropdown(
           id='time',
           options=get_intervals(),
           value=Interval.DAY.value,
           multi=False,
           persistence = True,
           persistence_type = 'session'
        ),
    )
```

However, if you need to keep the selection indefinitely within that browser on that computer you could simply use  ***persistence = True*** because the 'local' type is the default.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best solution, but regarding to [plotly documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks) I managed to do it like this:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('time', 'value'),
    Output('memory-intervals', 'data'),
    Input('time', 'value'),
    Input('memory-intervals', 'data'),
    Input('memory-intervals', 'modified_timestamp'),
)
def select_interval(dd_interval, memory_interval, timestamp):
    ctx = dash.callback_context
    trigger_id = ctx.triggered[0]["prop_id"].split(".")[0]

    if trigger_id == 'time':
        interval = dd_interval
    elif timestamp == -1 or memory_interval is None:
        interval = Interval.DAY.value
    else:
        interval = memory_interval

    return interval, interval
```